# NavigationDrawer with only one activity and different fragments layout? (like Youtube App)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I've implemented a NavigationDrawer and have now one activity and switch only the fragments.

But now I don't know how to go further. I've the MainActivity with the main_activity.xml and if I understood it right, the main_activity.xml is the base of all the layout. But if I now choose my first menu point in the NavigationDrawer, I want only a simple TextView (single fragment I think), the second menu point should be a Listview with different screen support (two fragments side by side for tablets, one fragment after the other for phones).
In the main_activity.xml is one activity or two activities declared. How can I handle this?

In the Youtube App it works like a charm and every menu point leads to a specific layout.